# Why can't I create a template function with an optional UnaryPredicate argument?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to create a templated function with an optional argument and I'm having trouble understanding why the compile fails. This is my test (contrived) code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class UnaryPredicate>
int GetCountIf(std::vector<int> v, UnaryPredicate pred = [](auto) { return true; }) {
  int count=0;
  for (auto i: v) {
    if (pred(i)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::cout << "NumOddElements=" << GetCountIf(v, [](auto val) { return (val % 2 == 1); }) << '\n';
  // std::cout << "NumElements=" << GetCountIf(v) << '\n';
}
```

The code compiles only if I call `GetCountIf()` with both arguments. If I try to pass it only 1 argument, compilation fails with this error:

> main.cpp:18:34: error: no matching function for call to 'GetCountIf'
>   std::cout << "NumElements=" << GetCountIf(v) << '\n';
>                                    ^~~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:5:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument
>   'UnaryPredicate' int GetCountIf(std::vector v, UnaryPredicate
>   pred =  { return true; }) {
>       ^ 1 error generated.

When the compiler comes across a call to `GetCountIf` with only 1 argument, why is it not able to deduce that the type of the optional lambda? If I explicitly specify the type of the predicate like this, it works:

```cpp
template <typename T, class UnaryPredicate = std::function<bool(T)>>
int GetCountIf(std::vector<T> v, UnaryPredicate pred = [](T) { return true;}) {
  ...
}
```

Why does this work?

(I'm using C++14)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the default value of function parameter won't be used for template argument deduction of template parameter; which leads to template argument deduction failure, the type of `UnaryPredicate` can't be deduced.

See [non-deduced contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 4) A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function
>   parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call
>   for which argument deduction is being done:
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename F>
> void f(const std::vector<T>& v, const F& comp = std::less<T>());
> std::vector<std::string> v(3);
> f(v); // P1 = const std::vector<T>&, A1 = std::vector<std::string> lvalue
>       // P1/A1 deduced T = std::string
>       // P2 = const F&, A2 = std::less<std::string> rvalue
>       // P2 is non-deduced context for F (template parameter) used in the
>       // parameter type (const F&) of the function parameter comp,
>       // that has a default argument that is being used in the call f(v)
> ```

and

> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function
>   default argument:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> void f(T = 5, T = 7);
>
> void g()
> {
>     f(1);     // OK: calls f<int>(1, 7)
>     f();      // error: cannot deduce T
>     f<int>(); // OK: calls f<int>(5, 7)
> }
> ```

On the other hand, if you specify a default value `std::function<bool(T)>` for template parameter `UnaryPredicate`, then it'll be used as the type for `UnaryPredicate` if the argument for `UnaryPredicate` is not explicitly specified or not be deduced.

Comment: A default parameter of `bool(T)` would do the trick and not need the type erasure of `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks, type deduction never fails to make my head spin. @user975989 I like `bool(T)` better than using the `std::function` wrapper. Thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 0):

Default argument does participate to deduction of the type, so the behavior you observe.

As alternative, you might create overloads:

```
template <class UnaryPredicate>
int GetCountIf(const std::vector<int>& v, UnaryPredicate pred) {
    int count = 0;
    for (auto i: v) {
        if (pred(i)) {
          count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int GetCountIf(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    return GetCountIf(v, [](auto) { return true; }); // return v.size(); // :-)
}
```